# How can I replace whole input field with its value in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Say, I have an html input field.

```
  <input type='text' class='txtData' />
```

In documentready method I set value of that input field.

```
  $(".txtData").val(2);
```

Now I convert this html input field into string like below.

```
  var sText = "<input type='text' class='txtData' />";
```

Now I want to replace this sText with $(.txtData).val().

How can I solve this? I google a lot but not find any solution

I find below solution which replace whole sText to " ".

```
  sText.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");
```

But how can I replace it with selected input field's value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sText` contains a string. So you cannot treat it as if it were a DOM Element. In other words, the string referred to by `sText` does not have a value property.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do

Comment: @Randy, thanks sir for you reply. Is there any way that can solve my need? Any idea?

Comment: `sText = "<span>" + $('.txtData').val() + "</span>"` and append it in place of the text box?

Comment: @brk, I want to replace whole input field with it's value.

Comment: That's the point though....it is not an _input field_ that `sText` points to. It has no value property!

Comment: @RandyCasburn, yes I can understand :(

Comment: use `parseHTML` to convert string to html and then operate on the resultant variable.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `string` to `html` using `JQuery.parseHTML` and then use the variable to update value.

example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         var sText = "<input type='text' value='21' class='txtData' />";
         var html = $.parseHTML(sText);
          //alert('before update '+$(html).val())
          console.log('before update '+$(html).val());
         $(html).val(19);
          //alert('after update '+$(html).val())
           console.log('after update '+$(html).val());

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button>UPDATE TEST</button>

</body>
</html>
```